# Matching Nested Loops Elements

Tags: java, lambda

I have 2 list of lists like

```
List<List<A>> list1;
List<List<B>> list2;
```

These A and B classes have id field.

```
class A{
   String id;
   String name;
}

class B{
   String id;
}
```

I can match these elements and manipulate B instances *name* field in a 4 nested loops

```
for(List<A> l1: list1){
   for(A a : l1){
      for(List<B> l2: list2){
         for(B b : l2){
            if(b.id.equals(a.id))
               b.name = "X";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I try to find wiser solution. **Is there any way to match them in 2 nested loops ?**

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more, especially what exactly you're trying to do and what you've tried so far. Why are those lists of lists? Are the elements unique or could there be duplicates in different inner lists (i.e. something like `[[B1,B2], [B1,B3]]`?

Comment: Elements are in ArrayList and not unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single `Stream` in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
list1.stream()
     .flatMap(List::stream)
     .map(A::getId)
     .distinct()
     .forEach(id -> list2.forEach(bList -> bList.forEach(b -> { if (b.id.equals(id)) b.name = "X";  })));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 stream API.

First collect all the **A** objects' ids into a Set or a Map(if you want to access that object) and then check for every B object if it exists in Set/Map.

```
Set<Integer> idSet = list1.stream().flatMap(aList -> aList.stream()).map(A::id).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

then

```
for(List<B> l2: list2){
     for(B b : l2){
        if(idSet.contains(b.id))
           b.name = "X";
     }
 }
```

It can also be done without stream API by running two loops for list1.